# iOS swift | Not getting the latest variable value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get values from my Database and show them in the app but I always get the last value that was read.

I have a QR code that I scan. That calls a php script returning JSON.
I manage to capture the values corresponding to the QR code.

The Output in the Xcode console is the correct value. However, when I try to display the values in my App I always get the values of the previous QR code.

```
let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Check-IN", message: "Check-In Ticket \(decodedURL)", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Check-in", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/get_data?t="+decodedURL)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
               do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                self.res_lastTitle = res.title
                self.res_lastVariante = res.titel_variante
                self.res_lastStatus_msg = res.status_msg
                print(res.title)
                print(res.status_msg)
                print(decodedURL)
               } catch let error {
                  print(error)
               }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        let resultPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Title"+self.res_lastTitle, message: self.res_lastStatus_msg, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
        resultPrompt.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(resultPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
    
    alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertPrompt.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I access the current value?

Comment: The download task returns asynchronously so the code that follows the async block is run before the block returns the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

`task.resume()` will start async task.
so next lines will be executed before network request finished.
You need to move your UI code inside dataTask response block (and make sure to execute it in main thread)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using DispatchSemaphore

before DataTask:
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

after decoding the JSON:
semaphore.signal()

and finaly after task.resume():
semaphore.wait()